# Best way to develop OS free npruntime plugin

Tags: plugins, npapi, browser-plugin, npruntime

I'm going to implement a npruntime plugin which will work on Chrome, Mozilla FF(windows/mac) and Safari(windows/mac). That plugin can draw images and will have some UI control.
I don't want to re-program the plugin for each OS platform if possible.

Using firebreath(framework for plugin) + Qt lib seems to be the only way to handle those problems I've been researching.

Is there other way to do it other than with firebreath and Qt lib?
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your UI requirements, but a relatively straight-forward way would be to do the drawing with OpenGL and provide the UI in the web-page.

To get started with OpenGL with FireBreath on Windows [see here](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/OpenGL+Plugin), for OS X [see here](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/examples/BasicMediaPlayer/Mac/BasicMediaPlayerPluginMac.mm).

There is also the [QtBrowserPlugin](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/developingplugins.html), but apparently it's still broken on OS X.